How can i copy an Azure VM snapshot to Azure Storage?
I create a VM snapshot and try to copy it to Azure Storage as follows
subscriptionId="xxxx"
resourceGroupName="xxx" 
snapshotName="snap1"
sasExpiryDuration=3600
storageAccountName="testsa"
storageContainerName="test"
storageAccountKey="xxxx"
destinationVHDFileName="sample.vhd"

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName - 
-duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --account-name $storageAccountName --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName  --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas

I then try to copy to a local pc as follows:
 $filename=  'c:\snapshots\' + $snapshotName
 az storage blob download --container-name 'mycontainer' --name $snapshotName --file 
 $filename --account-name 'mystorageaccount' --account-key <my-key>

the file gets copied to the local drive but the issue is that the size is 0 bytes.
Why is the size 0 bytes and how can i copy the snapshot to local drive ?


Why is the size 0 bytes, and how can I copy the snapshot to the local drive?

This situation occurs when the snapshot is not copied successfully to your storage account.
After copying from the snapshot to Azure Blob Storage using the command az storage blob copy start,This command takes time to copy from the snapshot to Azure Blob Storage. you need to verify if it has been copied or not using the command below.
Here is the command to verify the file status:
Command:
az storage blob show --account-name "venkat123" --account-key "xxxx"  --container-name "test" --name "sample.vhd"

Output:
xxxx az storage blob show --account-name "venkat123" --account-key "xxxx"  --container-name "test" --name "sample.vhd"
{
"copy": {
      "completionTime": null,
      "destinationSnapshot": null,
      "id": "e4f1bcd7-8549-47c3-82f1-d49f32cc6dfb",
      "incrementalCopy": null,
      "progress": "32213303808/32213303808",
      "source": xxxx",
      "status": "success",
      "statusDescription": null
    }


Now, after seeing the status is successful, I ran the same command in my environment to download from blob to local, and it executed successfully and downloaded successfully.
Command:
$snapshotName="test.vhd"
$filename=  'C:\demo\' + $snapshotName
az storage blob download --container-name 'test' --name $snapshotName --file $filename --account-name 'venkat123' --account-key "Mxxxxx"

Output:
$snapshotName="xxx"
$filename=  'C:\demo\' + $snapshotName
az storage blob download --container-name 'test' --name $snapshotName --file $filename --account-name 'venkat123' --account-key "Mxxxxx" 
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000% 
"copy": {
      "completionTime": null,
      "destinationSnapshot": null,
      "id": "1b9f4234-c276-4a26-8f87-de703c88fdb7",
      "incrementalCopy": null,
      "progress": "4294967808/4294967808",
      "source": "hxxxxxxx",
      "status": "success",
      "statusDescription": null
    },


For larger file downloads, I suggest you refer to the azcopy command.
File:


So when i do the copy to storage how long do i wait to see if it is successful ? Do i need to put it in a loop and keep running the command az storage blob show --account-name "venkat123" --account-key "xxxx"  --container-name "test" --name "sample.vhd" until it is successful ?

Depends upon your size of the disk it will take time.

Yeah, you can make use of loop until the command will get successful.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78313079/why-is-a-azure-vm-snapshot-0-bytes-in-size-when-copied-to-a-storage-account-in-a?noredirect=1#comment138065944_78313079.

Hope this address your issue.
